# Define environment variable in a subshell with heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, heredoc

Background: testing a bash script inside a pod where default user does not have sudo rights so that user cannot user vim or nano to create a `.sh` file so I have to find a way around with `cat << EOF >> test.sh`.
I am doing some local test to make sure it's working properly first. Locally I am creating a file `test.sh` with nano. See below

```
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
VAR="Test"
echo $VAR
```

When I cat it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
VAR="Test"
echo $VAR%
```

I save `test.sh` , made it execuatble `chmod +x test.sh` and ran it with `./test.sh` The output:

```
Test
```

Now when I try to mimic the same behavior in a bash heredoc instead this is the command I use:

```
cat <<EOF >> test.sh
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
VAR="Test"
echo $VAR
EOF
```

I saved it and made it execuatble as well. The cat output is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
VAR="Test"
echo
```

So obviously running it wouldn't work. The output null.
I think the issue I am facing is that the environment variable `$VAR` is not defined properly inside the subshell using heredoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this:

```
cat <<EOF >> test.sh
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
VAR="Test"
echo $VAR
EOF
```

...that `$VAR` is expanded *by your current shell* (just like writing something like `echo "$VAR"`). If you want to suppress variable expansion inside your heredoc, you can quote it (note the quotes around `'EOF'`):

```
cat <<'EOF' >> test.sh
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
VAR="Test"
echo $VAR
EOF
```

This inhibits variable expansion just like single quotes (`echo '$VAR'`).

Comment: You are my hero :)